# Why this string.search doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, string

Why this returns a `0` as expected

`'https://www.site.com/abc?sk=1'.search('https://www.site.com/abc?')`

But this returns a `-1` as `0` is expected?

`'https://www.site.com/abc?sk=1'.search('https://www.site.com/abc?sk')`

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: `?` is a reserved character in regular expression, you may need to escape it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the `?` has a special meaning in regular expressions.

Use `indexOf` instead (which works with plain strings) when you don't need regular expressions:

```
'https://www.site.com/abc?sk=1'.indexOf('https://www.site.com/abc?sk')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>    
if('https://www.site.com/abc?sk=1'.indexOf('https://www.site.com/abc?sk')>=0){ 
   //Do something you want
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you do `>=`? Then it would also match `http://fishing.com/https://www.site.com`